# How to rewrite number of specific url to subdomain via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, dns, url-rewriting, subdomain

I have a main domain and many subdomains on it now i want to redirect main domain to its HTTPS and other domains to its subdomain for example:

- main.com redirects to https://main.com
- domain1.com redirects to domain1.main.com
- domain2.com redirects to domain2.main.com

now i using this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.main.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^main.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.main.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

this code redirect main.com only and other domains must check in index.php and redirect to specific subdomain, i want to perform whole  work in htaccess.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?main\.com
RewriteRule ^ https://www.main.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:www\.)?main\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?([^.]+)\.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%1.main.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

It makes sense to start out using a `R=302` *temporary* redirection at first and only change that to a `R=301` *permanent* redirection once everything works as desired.

Obviously this requires that requests to those other domains are handled by the http host which implements this rule set. So you most likely want to define either host aliases for those domains or use a default virtual host inside your http server.

Comment: Sorry, there was a trivial typo in the second rewriting rule definition, I fixed that above. Apart from that I don't really know what you mean by "even redirecting main domain to https". Sure it does, that is what makes sense and what your original rule set also does.

Comment: thank you for your attention, redirecting to HTTPS of main.com working fine but second part not works domain1.com not redirect to domain1.main.com.

Comment: I made another small change to fix that. Sorry for those trivial mistakes. And please allow for a general note about this: you really should be able to spot these details yourself. You should not just copy some code you find or are given, you need to understand the code. Which also means that you should be able to adjust it to your specific situation and needs.

Comment: Nice Job! it working fine and about your general note, you are right and i must read more about htaccess rules, thank you again.

Comment: That's the spirit: to put you on track: there is no such thing as a "htaccess rule". Files usually named ".htaccess" are configuration files, _distributed_ configuration files as opposed to the centralized, main configuration files of the apache http server. Such a configurtion file can hold various things, not just rewriting rules. So you actually want to read about 1. .htaccess style files (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html) and 2. the rewriting module (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).